# Is there a generic function that takes a data structure and returns all ints in it?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

I think the type signature would look like `f :: a -> [Int]`
input data would look like `data NamedPoint = NamedPoint String Int Int`

```
data Person = Name Int Int Int
```

and using it in the REPL would look like this:

```
>> let namedPoint = NamedPoint "hey" 1 2
>> let tommy = Person "Tommy" 1 2 3
>> f namedPoint
>> [1,2] 
>> f Tommy
>> [1,2,3]
```

I think this would be useful as an alternative to records for when you are too lazy to write getters for data with alot of parameters.

Comment: If the input data is going to be ``NamedPoint`` why cannot the function be typed as ``f :: NamedPoint -> [Int]``?

Comment: In this case it could. But I was thinking this behavior could be useful for extracting generalized types. ill edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: For this task, uniplate is the simplest choice.  Your f is simply the universeBi function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`Data`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html) class is capable of this. I've found the easiest way to work with it is with the [`template`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.11/docs/Data-Data-Lens.html#v:template) traversal from the [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package. This essentially lets you set or get anything with a `Data` instance. In ghci:

```
> import Data.Data
> import Control.Lens
> import Data.Data.Lens

> -- Data is a derivable class
> :set -XDeriveDataTypeable
> data NamedPoint = NamedPoint String Int Int deriving (Data, Show)
> data Person = Name String Int Int Int deriving (Data, Show)
> let namedPoint = NamedPoint "hey" 1 2
> let tommy = Name "Tommy" 1 2 3

> let ints = toListOf template :: Data a => a -> [Int]
> ints namedPoint
[1,2]
> ints tommy
[1,2,3]
```

Because `template` is a traversal, you can also map over values (but you may need to specify the type):

```
> namedPoint & template *~ (10 :: Int)
NamedPoint "hey" 10 20
> import Data.Char
> tommy & template %~ toUpper
Name "TOMMY" 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not possible with a function of the type signature you described. Think about what the `f :: a -> [Int]` means: `f` is supposed to be a function that takes a value of **any** possible type and returns a list of `Int`s. How should such a function be defined? The only possible definition is that it ignores the argument and returns a constant value, something like

```
f :: a -> [Int]
f _ = [0]
```

If you know what your `a` is going to be, why not just use that type? Like this:

```
f :: NamedPoint -> [Int]
f (NamedPoint _ a b) = [a, b]
```

If you wanted some "general" function returning all `Int`s from a datatype, one option would be to define a typeclass

```
class IntContainer a where
    f :: a -> [Int]
```

and then define instances for the datatypes you are interested in

```
instance IntContainer NamedPoint where
    f (NamedPoint _ a b) = [a, b]
```

Comment: "this is not possible" is a bit of an overstatement — it's not trivial and not, strictly speaking, possible with the exact signature mentioned (`a :: [Int]`) but it's definitely possible to achieve what the OP asks.

Comment: @ErikAllik Thanks for your notice, I didn't know. I edited the answer to be more accurate.